# Note: could not open file /home/.ncviewrc for reading Error: Can't open display:

Tags: macos, tcsh, x11-forwarding

I am using macOS Monterey (12.4).

I used `ssh -X username@asasd.de` for login.

Modules that are already loaded in system.
Module list:

1. intel-oneapi-compilers/2022.0.1-gcc-11.2.0
2. openmpi/4.1.2-intel-2021.5.0
3. netcdf-c/4.8.1-openmpi-4.1.2-intel-2021.5.0
4. netcdf-fortran/4.5.3-openmpi-4.1.2-intel-2021.5.0
5. intel-oneapi-mkl/2022.0.1-gcc-11.2.0
6. ncview/2.1.8-gcc-11.2.0
7. hdf5/1.12.1-threadsafe-intel-2021.5.0

After running a model in a /work/ directory I generate a file "file.cdf" there.

I want to open it with ncview.
So I did : $ ncview file.cdf and I am getting this error.

```
Ncview 2.1.8 David W. Pierce  8 March 2017
http://meteora.ucsd.edu:80/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html
Copyright (C) 1993 through 2015, David W. Pierce
Ncview comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `ncview -w'.
This is free software licensed under the Gnu General Public License version 3; type `ncview -c' for redistribution details.


Note: could not open file /home/.ncviewrc for reading
Error: Can't open display:
```

Comment: Do you have an X Window system running on your Mac? Without it, the `-X` of `ssh` is going to be useless and you will not be able to run `ncview`, which is an X11 application. The missing `.ncviewrc` is just a note; the missing `DISPLAY` variable (due to missing X11) is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users:
I was also facing the same issue. It was solved for me after installing Xquartz on my local machine. https://www.xquartz.org/

I hope it works for you.